# Why my record rule doesn't grant me the access right in odoo

Tags: odoo

Here is my access right on Purchase order model and only read permission is allowed.
[image]

And here is my record rules on the same model with full access right.
[image]

But I found that I still cannot update/create records on this model.Why?

Answer (score 0):

You have modified Odoo standard purchase user access rights which is not advisable.

Allow read, write, create & delete access rights to purchase user role in view access rights.